# Python odd spaces when printing from while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the code:

```
 macraw = []
for user in c.get_users():
    macraw.append(user.get('mac'))

count = 0
x = 0

while (count < len(macraw)):
    client_list = c.get_client(macraw[x])
    raw_tx = float(client_list.get('tx_bytes'))
    byte_to_gb = raw_tx / 10**9
    byte_to_mb = raw_tx / 10**6
    timestamp1 = client_list['first_seen']
    timestamp2 = client_list['last_seen']
    readable1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp1)
    readable2 = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp2)
    dailytime = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)
    if readable2 > dailytime:
        if byte_to_gb > 1:
            print '<b>%s</b> last seen: <b>%s</b> total download usage --> <b>%s</b> GB' % (client_list.get('hostname'),readable2,round(byte_to_gb, 2))
        else:
            print '<b>%s</b> last seen: <b>%s</b> total download usage --> <b>%s</b> MB' % (client_list.get('hostname'),readable2,round(byte_to_mb, 2))
    else:
        pass

    count = count + 1
    x = x + 1
    print '<br/><br/>'
```

The output :

```
 History of All Clients Last 24 Hours
HP1972B8 last seen: 2019-03-15 10:20:13 total download usage --> 2.95 MB 

LAPTOP-H3D3OG4A last seen: 2019-03-15 10:20:13 total download usage --> 35.62 MB 



HPF91643 last seen: 2019-03-15 10:20:55 total download usage --> 0.95 MB 

HP823BA5 last seen: 2019-03-15 10:20:55 total download usage --> 10.75 MB 



Nevans-iPhone last seen: 2019-03-14 10:38:52 total download usage --> 71.5 GB 





Jaymes-iPhone-2 last seen: 2019-03-15 10:20:55 total download usage --> 1.79 MB 











Shawns-iPhone last seen: 2019-03-14 12:13:31 total download usage --> 1.91 GB
```

I'm trying to get rid of all those blank spaces between the rows. Before I implemented the - 1 days with timedelta, it was fine. Each rows was properly
populated one after each other. Now, since I'm removing some lines that I don't need, it's like they've been replaced with a blank line for some reason.

I would simply like them gone and print next line on top of each others.

Thanks for any input :)

EDIT:

Here's the code BEFORE removing the datetimes that are bigger than 1 days:

```
if usersnames_flag == "ON":
print '<h1> History of All Clients Ever </h1>'
macraw = []
for user in c.get_users():
    macraw.append(user.get('mac'))

count = 0
x = 0

while (count < len(macraw)):
    client_list = c.get_client(macraw[x])
    raw_tx = float(client_list.get("tx_bytes"))
    byte_to_gb = raw_tx / 10**9
    byte_to_mb = raw_tx / 10**6
    readable = time.ctime(client_list['first_seen'])
    readable1 = time.ctime(client_list['last_seen'])
    if byte_to_gb > 1:
        print '<b>%s</b> with MAC <b>%s</b> first seen: <b>%s</b> last seen: <b>%s</b> total download usage --> <b>%s</b> GB' % (client_list.get('hostname'),client_list["mac"],readable,readable1,round(byte_to_gb, 2))
    else:
        print '<b>%s</b> with MAC <b>%s</b> first seen: <b>%s</b> last seen: <b>%s</b> total download usage --> <b>%s</b> MB' % (client_list.get('hostname'),client_list["mac"],readable,readable1,round(byte_to_mb, 2))
    count = count + 1
    x = x + 1
    print '<br/><br/>'
```

The output is fine for this part, it prints them one after each others.

Yes there is some HTML in this script (CGI)

Comment: you probably have empty `print` statements somewhere else in some unshown code

Comment: You're actively printing them. You have `print '<br/><br/>'` on every iteration, regardless if anything else was actually printed. Whatever is displaying the output apparently interprets the strings as HTML

Comment: Thanks roganjosh it's working now, modified the loop and moved the <br/>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
if readable2 > dailytime:
        if byte_to_gb > 1:
            print '<b>%s</b> last seen: <b>%s</b> total download usage --> <b>%s</b> GB \n' % (client_list.get('hostname'),readable2,round(byte_to_gb, 2))
        else:
            print '<b>%s</b> last seen: <b>%s</b> total download usage --> <b>%s</b> MB \n' % (client_list.get('hostname'),readable2,round(byte_to_mb, 2))
    else:
        pass

    count = count + 1
    x = x + 1
```

To me it looks like that the last last print statement is the likely culprit. You may want to checkout the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) from the standard library, I think it might suite your needs a bit more. Also if you're new to Python, python 3 is probably a better route to take.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I have to use python2 for this tool, it's using an API that was written for python2 only.

Comment: see my edit, try it out without the final print statement. Alternatively add a print statement to the final else: block and I'm pretty sure it's cases in your while loop that fails readable2 > dailytime that get passed to the final print statement in your original example

Comment: Got it to work! My <br/> at the end of the while loop was causing the problem. Moved the <br/> inside the second if loop (byte_to_gb) and it works!

Comment: `code` LAPTOP-H3D3OG4A last seen: 2019-03-15 13:23:45 total download usage --> 45.56 MB 

Jaymes-iPhone-2 last seen: 2019-03-15 12:39:01 total download usage --> 10.43 GB 

Jaymes-iPhone last seen: 2019-03-14 14:36:33 total download usage --> 6.54 GB 

Galaxy-S8 last seen: 2019-03-15 13:23:45 total download usage --> 58.69 MB

Comment: Great! if you could mark my answer as a solution it'll help other's who may happen upon this question in the future.